# Python Pandas: How to grab column of values from .agg and put into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to just get the sum of 'ride_value' by this groupby. How do I do that?

```
df.groupby(['start_lat_3', 'start_lng_3'])['ride_value'].agg(['sum'])
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby(['start_lat_3', 'start_lng_3'])['ride_value'].agg(['sum'])
```

But of course, that doesn't work because the right-hand side is a Pandas DataFrame.

I tried:

```
df.groupby(['start_lat_3', 'start_lng_3'])['ride_value'].agg(['sum'])[2]
df.groupby(['start_lat_3', 'start_lng_3'])['ride_value'].agg(['sum'])[['sum']]
df.groupby(['start_lat_3', 'start_lng_3'])['ride_value'].agg(['sum'])['sum']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring back a full df input, transform

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby(['start_lat_3', 'start_lng_3'])['ride_value'].transform('sum')
```

If you want it summarised, agg

```
df.groupby(['start_lat_3', 'start_lng_3']).agg({'ride_value':'sum'})
```